# Low-level Lua interpreter

Tags: lua

Is there a way to run Lua code from a C/C++ program at a more fine-grained level than a standard "lua_pcall" function call? Ideally I'd like to be able to loop over a list of low-level bytecode instructions (assuming it has such things) and run them one by one, so that I could write my own scheduler which had more control of things than just running a complete Lua function from start to finish.

The reason I want to do this is because I wish to implement C functions which Lua code can call which would cause the program to wait until a certain (potentially long-winded) action had completed before continuing execution. There would be a high proportion of such function calls in a typical Lua script, so the idea of rewriting it to use callbacks once the action has completed isn't really practical.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps side-stepping the question, but you could use Lua coroutines rather than custom C stuff to wait until some event occurs.

For example, one coroutine could call a waitForEvent() function. In there, you can switch to another coro until that event occurs, then resume the first one. Take a look at [the lua coro docs](http://www.lua.org/pil/9.1.html) for more about that.

Comment: This solution seems to have a lot of potential - particularly given that the C API can yield/resume coroutines itself.

Answer (score 6):

Jder's suggestion to use coroutines will work very well if you can write those long waiting C routines using Lua's cooperative threading (explicit yield) feature. You'll still use lua_pcall() to enter Lua, but the entry point will be your coroutine manager function.

This only works though if the C routines don't do anything while they wait. If they are long running because they calculate something for example, then you need to run multiple OS threads. Lua is threadsafe -- just create multiple threads and run lua_open() in each thread.

From http://www.lua.org/pil/24.1.html

> The Lua library defines no global
>   variables at all. It keeps all its
>   state in the dynamic structure
>   lua_State and a pointer to this
>   structure is passed as an argument to
>   all functions inside Lua. This
>   implementation makes Lua reentrant and
>   ready to be used in multithreaded
>   code.

You can also combine the two approaches. If you have a wrapper Lua function to start an OS thread, you can yield after you start the thread. The coroutine manager will keep track of threads and continue a coroutine when the thread it started has finished. This lets you use a single Lua interpreter with multiple worker threads running pure C code.

Answer (score 5):

If you go the OS threading way, please have a look at [Lua Lanes](http://luaforge.net/frs/?group_id=265). I would see it the perfect solution to what you're trying to achieve (= throw one addon module to the mix and you'll be making clear, understandable and simple code with multithreading seamlessly built in).

Please tell us how your issue got solved. :)

Comment: Thanks for the link - I'll definitely take a look into this

Answer (score 2):

Does the [debugging interface](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#3.8) help?